# Wrong reputation change for "earlier today" section of the feed page in the iOS app

Tags: bug, ios-app

In the Feed page of the iOS app I see "+197" reputation change in the "earlier today" section:

> [image: 197]

But there is not for *"today"* actually as seen via the Reputation tab:

> [image: rep]

Also, reputation graph on web shows radically different values:

> [image: graph]

- App Version: 1.6.2.5
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.2 (Build 14C92)

Comment: Your timezone isn't UTC right? I'm pretty sure that the "earlier today" etc sections are based on duration (i.e. today is anything <24 hours ago) but everything else is based off UTC time. Although I may be completely wrong...

Comment: Actually, looking again you've got reputation there that wasn't from today or yesterday... when was all that reputation actually from?

Comment: @Cai seems that "earlier today" is a sum of rep from Dec 28 to today (if graph for web is correct).