# Daily totals in mobile app

Tags: feature-request, android-app, ios-app

On the website, when I click the rep drop down, I get a convenient total for the day across the different exchanges.

[image]

This is missing from the mobile app in iOS.

[image]

I'm left with either counting it up myself or switching to the browser.

Can we get those same totals in the mobile app?

Comment: At the end of the day (00:00), all the reputation you earned is summed up and shown in the feed.

Comment: @devRicher and it may be [wrong](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289099/339911).